# Friedman chi-squared = 0. What does it mean?

Tags: chi-squared-test, p-value, friedman-test

My data was paired and do not fit normality. So I used a Friedman test.However, the result turn out to be Friedman chi-squared = 0, df = 1, p-value = 1. How do this happen?

My data was in this way:

```
    I    II
1   2    1
2   4    1
3   5    0
4   0    2
5  14    3
6  11    3
7   7    6
8   8    9
9  12   19
10 15   13
11 19   32
12 22   74
13 15    1
14  2    1
15  2    4
16  1    6
17  5    9
18  1    8
19  6    6
20  8   11
21 12   17
22 26   22
23 38   29
24 43   58
25 71   20
```

Comment: Can you show a better layout of your data so we can exactly understand what is going on?  Also, are you calculating this using some software, if so perhaps you can show us the commands you are using that gets you the output shown?

Comment: Why not just use a sign test? Actually, if these are counts, why not a chi-square, a poisson or binomial GLM, or possibly even a GLMM?

Comment: @BabakP I observed moth oviposition on leaf upper surface and down surface (n=800/time, 25 times). I am using R. My code is:oviposition<-matrix(c(up,down,nrow=25,byrow=T,dimnames=list(1:25,c("up","down")))     friedman.test(ovipostion)

Comment: With your above data in two columns in a data frame (here called `a`), I believe an appropriate analysis of your data is: `expec <- outer(rowSums(a),c(.5,.5));
(chisq <- sum((a-expec)^2/expec));
pchisq(chisq,df=dim(a)[1],lower=FALSE)` . Note that this is NOT a chisq test of independence.

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you for you code. But I am puzzled with the result. I checked the Language reference,  pchisq gives the distribution function. I followed your code and got the a value of 0.00112239. What does it mean? In 0.05 confident level, could I say there is significant difference between mean of up(I) and down(II)?

Comment: @jack, The mean rank of both your columns is the same, 1.5 (12 values are bigger in column I and 12 values are bigger in column II, 1 is tied). Of course, there is no difference at all according to Friedman or sign tests. Is it unsatisfactory for you?

Comment: @ttnphns, I am satisfied with the result in this up and down case. The result of sign test and friedman test support the same result and it fits my observation. However, in the case of oviposition on leaf and apple, things get weird. The data form is same as up and down. However, the result of sign test and friedman test is  
opponent. The p value of friedman test is 0.5127, while p value of sign test is 0.004077. I had tried wicox test as well, the p value is 0.06777. I do not know which one should I take.

Comment: I don't follow the thead, so don't know about "oviposition on leaf and apple" data. Can you show that data with comments about the weirdness - in your question?

Comment: Actually, Jack, that chi-squared code I gave above is wrong, sorry. As that stands that's effectively doing an overall test of whether the pairs individually differ from equality, not whether there's a tendency toward one group or the other. It's highly significant because some pairs have a high proportion one direction and other pairs go the other way. Overall, there's not much tendency either way. I'll have to fix it.

Comment: In fact, the individual proportions are (highly) inconsistent with the assumption that the rows are binomial with a consistent proportion, which invalidates the assumptions of doing what I was trying to do anyway. I think you might be left with some form of GLMM to account for that heterogeneity, but I can pretty clearly see you won't reject the null that on average there's no tendency in a particular direction. (Also, it will be the case that your friedman test was right; I also get a p-value of 1 for the sign test.)

Comment: One possibility for fixing that chi-square would be to partition that chi-square into two components; one component with 24 df for heterogeneity of proportion (the usual chi-square for independence) and one component with 1 df for overall deviation from 0.5. That would serve to illustrate both the main pieces of information. I just have to double check some details for that

Answer (score 1):

The p-value for the Friedman test is indeed 1.

The reason why the p-value for the Friedman is 1 is that 12 pairs have the group I value higher, and 12 pairs have the group II value higher (with one tie, in the 19th row).

That is to say, the sample is as perfectly consistent with no difference (measured the way the Friedman statistic does) as it is possible to be.

A two-tailed sign test would give the same result (p-value is 1), but because we need to explicitly count the cases, it makes it more immediately obvious what is going on:

[image]

Which is that nothing is going on. There's not the slightest indication of any difference.